# In Hotchocolate Graphql, not able to upload file using banana cake popup, getting server error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

[HotChocolateFileUploadError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orMdU.png)

I am using Hotchocolate nuget package to implement GraphQL using Banana Cake Pop. I have implemented File upload using the UploadType.

```
builder.Services
                    .AddGraphQLServer()
                    .AddQueryType<Query>()
                    .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
                    .AddType<UploadType>()
                    .AddTypeExtension<AuthorExtensions>()
                    .AddMutationConventions();
```

**Mutation Request:**

```
mutation ($input:UploadProfilePictureInput!){
  uploadProfilePicture(input: $input){
    author{
      id
    }
  }
}

{
  "input": {"file": "ts.json", "authorId": 1}
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "message": "",
  "name": "ServerError",
  "statusCode": 404,
  "statusText": "",
  "bodyText": ""
}
```

I tried the same in postman as form data. Yet I am getting the same error.
Other queries otherthan uploading file I am able to get output in postman.
Please help me where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of Hot Chocolate we have added some security to the file upload and by default demand a preflight header.

`GraphQL-preflight:1`

https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/6188

In the newest Banana Cake Pop version we have added the header to the common headers in the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: I tried the same as above and its working. Thank you :)